# Background Geolocation For Ionic2

Tags: background, geolocation, ionic2

i'm trying to use background geolocation , i found this link :
[a link] https://www.joshmorony.com/adding-background-geolocation-t…/  .
 "Geoposition is not knwon " type script error .

ionic version :2.2.1 , node version :6.10.0 , cordova version:6.5.0 .any suggestion for ionic2 geoloca

```js
location-tracker :


import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Geolocation,Geoposition, BackgroundGeolocation } from 'ionic-native';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
 
@Injectable()
export class LocationTracker {
 
  public watch: any;    
  public lat: number = 0;
  public lng: number = 0;
 
  constructor(public zone: NgZone) {
 
  }
 
  startTracking() {
 // Background Tracking
 
  let config = {
    desiredAccuracy: 0,
    stationaryRadius: 20,
    distanceFilter: 10, 
    debug: true,
    interval: 2000 
  };
 
  BackgroundGeolocation.configure((location) => {
 
    console.log('BackgroundGeolocation:  ' + location.latitude + ',' + location.longitude);
 
    // Run update inside of Angular's zone
    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.lat = location.latitude;
      this.lng = location.longitude;
    });
 
   }, (err) => {
 
    console.log(err);
 
  }, config);
 
  // Turn ON the background-geolocation system.
  BackgroundGeolocation.start();
 
 
  // Foreground Tracking
 
  let options = {
    frequency: 3000, 
    enableHighAccuracy: true
  };
 
  this.watch = Geolocation.watchPosition(options).filter((p: any) => p.code === undefined).subscribe((position: Geoposition ) => {
 
    console.log(position);
 
    // Run update inside of Angular's zone
    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
      this.lng = position.coords.longitude;
    });
 
  });
 
  }
 
  stopTracking() {
 
 console.log('stopTracking');
 
  BackgroundGeolocation.finish();
  this.watch.unsubscribe();
 
  }
 
}
```

tion

Comment: Please show us the actual code ..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have already run the following commands;

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
npm install --save @ionic-native/geolocation
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation
npm install --save @ionic-native/background-geolocation
```

try importing the plugins as follows:

```
import { BackgroundGeolocation } from '@ionic-native/background-geolocation';
import { Geolocation, Geoposition } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
```